# Wavy screen and lines showing now and again in live streaming cam

Tags: live, streaming

I have setup a trial live streaming cam in my chicken coop to test this little camera. I am seeing some waves and lines in the feed now and again.

Does anyone know why this happens and what the fix is? I am using the RCA / BNC connector to connect to my video in and this is a 12v system running through 100' of wire.

Here is an example video (around :10 shows the most...):

I have this connected to my gamer PC which is more than powerful enough to process all this video if that could be an issue. Might it be the video capture mechanism? If so, anyone have a good card in mind?

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be analog signal degradation resulting in a loss of frame syncronization.  You may need to add a video amplifier on the end near the camera to boost the signal enough to get it to your computer or possibly use a device that can convert it to digital and stream it over a network connection directly.